# Changing text using Tinker Python

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

So far I'm having an issue changing the text in the changeable_label field I cant get a string working with text to change the text 'Null' to NW when the radiobutton 'North-West' is clicked. I dont know whether I need to create another 'if' function  or what...

```
#Import the Tkinter functions
from Tkinter import *

# Creating the windo
the_window = Tk()

# Title of window
the_window.title('Change colour')

# Label widget which has its properties modified
changeable_label = Label(the_window, text = 'Null',
                         font = ('Times', 48), fg = 'black')

# String variables which values change on selcetion of radio button
label_colour = StringVar()

# Creating an a function to change the labels text colour when the radio
# button is chosen
def change_colour():
    if label_colour.get() == 'NW':
        changeable_label['fg'] = 'black',
    elif label_colour.get() == 'NE':
        changeable_label['fg'] = 'green'
    elif label_colour.get() == 'SW':
        changeable_label['fg'] = 'blue'
    else:
        changeable_label['fg'] = 'yellow'

# Creating an a function to change the labels text when the radio
# button is chosen

# Creating the frame for the 4 buttons.
colour_buttons = Frame(the_window)

# Creating the Radio Buttons features
NW_button = Radiobutton(colour_buttons, text = 'North-West',
                         variable = label_colour, value = 'NW',
                         command = change_colour)
NE_button = Radiobutton(colour_buttons, text = 'North-East',
                           variable = label_colour, value = 'NE',
                           command = change_colour)
SW_button = Radiobutton(colour_buttons, text = 'South-West',
                          variable = label_colour, value = 'SW',
                          command = change_colour)
SE_button = Radiobutton(colour_buttons, text = 'South-East',
                          variable = label_colour, value = 'SE',
                          command = change_colour)



# Placing the 4 radio buttons on specific rows, columns, locations.
NW_button.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
NE_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)
SW_button.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W)
SE_button.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = W)

# Using the geomtry manager to pack the widgets onto the window.
margin = 8 # pixels
changeable_label.pack(padx = margin, pady = margin)
colour_buttons.pack(padx = margin, pady = margin)

# Start the event loop to react to user inputs
the_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see any code that shows you trying to change the text. You are changing the color, and changing the text is done in an identical manner, so what problem are you having changing the text?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
changeable_label = Label(the_window, textvariable = label_colour)
```

To let the label show the text of the radio option.
I would rename `label_colour` since is is not the colour but the direction.

One would also change your code to use a dictionairy.

```
if label_colour.get() == 'NW':
    changeable_label['fg'] = 'black',
elif label_colour.get() == 'NE':
    changeable_label['fg'] = 'green'
elif label_colour.get() == 'SW':
    changeable_label['fg'] = 'blue'
else:
    changeable_label['fg'] = 'yellow'
```

would become

```
label_foreground = {'NW': 'black', "NE" : 'green', 'SW' : 'blue', 'SE' : 'yellow'}
changeable_label['fg'] = label_foreground[label_colour.get()]
```

You can do the same for the text, if you wish. Have a read with `help(dict)`.

Comment: Cheers for the help, I just added another def.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question, I can't believe I
didn't see this earlier...

```
    def change_text():
if label_text.get() == 'NW':
    changeable_label['text'] = 'NW'
elif label_text.get() == 'NE':
    changeable_label['text'] = 'NE'
elif label_text.get() == 'SW':
    changeable_label['text'] = 'SW'
else:
    changeable_label['text'] = 'SE'
```

Comment: consider using a dictionairy or a list. They are created to replace large if constructs.